# MySQL duplicate and incorrect results

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as below:

```
**MUSICIAN**

musicianSurname

musicianForename

musicianNInumber   PK

musicianDOB

musicianAddress1   FK



**MUSICIAN_ADDRESS**

musicianTelNo

MusicianAddress1   PK

musicianAddress2

musicianPostcode
```

I want to query the database to say "show me all musicians names addresses and telephone numbers, here is my query:

```
 SELECT musician.musicianForename, musician.musicianSurname, musician_address.musicianaddress1, musician_address.musicianTelNo
FROM musician
JOIN musician_address;
```

And it returns the results like this (obviously wrong, all repeated with mismatched information). Please someone help!

```
Angela  Underpants  145 Acacia Avenue   01234567891
Angela  Underpants  26 Bobbo Road   0208562456
Angela  Underpants  45 Underfrock Road  01753526893
Angela  Underpants  9 Simple Drive  01587452326
Jack    Towslon 145 Acacia Avenue   01234567891
Jack    Towslon 26 Bobbo Road   0208562456
Jack    Towslon 45 Underfrock Road  01753526893
Jack    Towslon 9 Simple Drive  01587452326
Terry   Awesome 145 Acacia Avenue   01234567891
Terry   Awesome 26 Bobbo Road   0208562456
Terry   Awesome 45 Underfrock Road  01753526893
Terry   Awesome 9 Simple Drive  01587452326
Brad    Cobra   145 Acacia Avenue   01234567891
Brad    Cobra   26 Bobbo Road   0208562456
Brad    Cobra   45 Underfrock Road  01753526893
Brad    Cobra   9 Simple Drive  01587452326
Lara    Tehabsim    145 Acacia Avenue   01234567891
Lara    Tehabsim    26 Bobbo Road   0208562456
Lara    Tehabsim    45 Underfrock Road  01753526893
Lara    Tehabsim    9 Simple Drive  01587452326
Jennifer    Saunders    145 Acacia Avenue   01234567891
Jennifer    Saunders    26 Bobbo Road   0208562456
Jennifer    Saunders    45 Underfrock Road  01753526893
Jennifer    Saunders    9 Simple Drive  01587452326
Phil    Oades   145 Acacia Avenue   01234567891
Phil    Oades   26 Bobbo Road   0208562456
Phil    Oades   45 Underfrock Road  01753526893
Phil    Oades   9 Simple Drive  01587452326
Pat O'Cake  145 Acacia Avenue   01234567891
Pat O'Cake  26 Bobbo Road   0208562456
Pat O'Cake  45 Underfrock Road  01753526893
Pat O'Cake  9 Simple Drive  01587452326
James   McFab   145 Acacia Avenue   01234567891
James   McFab   26 Bobbo Road   0208562456
James   McFab   45 Underfrock Road  01753526893
James   McFab   9 Simple Drive  01587452326
```

Comment: You don't have ANY conditions on your join, so the database is doing a cross join: all possible combinations of records. You need a `join foo on X=Y` type construct to limit the possible combinationes.

Comment: It's OK to read a book or tutorial before just jumping in  - but whatever works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT musician.musicianForename, musician.musicianSurname,musician_address.musicianaddress1, musician_address.musicianTelNo
FROM  musician_address
JOIN  musician on 
MusicianAddress1.MusicianAddress1 = MUSICIAN.musicianAddress1  ;
```

I would also reconsider your database design. Having a primary key of an address is not the best use of a primary key and could cause problems.

Read http://sqlmag.com/database-administration/sql-design-how-choose-primary-key just a one of many articles on how to go about choosing a primary key.

Comment: Thanks, I got that to work. I know its not the best primary key but it is unique in the table so it'll do (hopefully). I'm having to throw this together in a real hurry. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.musicianForename, m.musicianSurname, 
       ma.musicianaddress1, ma.musicianTelNo
FROM musician m 
JOIN musician_address ma ON ma.musicianaddress1 = m.musicianaddress1;
```

This way you will get the address of each musician

You need a condition in your `JOIN`

Comment: Thanks, but when I do that, then it doesn't recognise the columns!

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'musician.musicianForename' in 'field list' 0.000 sec